# Should a bowling game use a 2d or a 3d physics engine?

Tags: physics, box2d, actionscript-3, physics-engine

I'm creating a bowling game in flash+as3. I'm new to physics engines, so, to start I've begun to learn Box2D since I've heard it's one of the most popular physics game engines.

Currently, I'm not sure if it's the best solution. I'm not sure even if I should use a 2D physics engine or if I should move to 3D physics engine.

As you can see in the attached screenshot of my game, the ball should move on the lane until it hits the pins. The game has some amount of 3D behavior.

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: A word of advise: It might be 10 years too late to start learning Flash. [This week even Adobe themselves declared it obsolete](https://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2017/07/adobe-flash-update.html).

Comment: Hi @Philipp ,you right. Though ,the reason I've decided to work with flash technology is, since i wanted to get better also with the animation tools they provide. still not sure if this is the best decision. I'm aware that game engines and frameworks as cocos2d,unity, js and html5 might be much more popular nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

When developing games it is important to separate the game *mechanics* from the game *representation* on the screen.

The game mechanics of bowling can be simplified to a pure 2d simulation by looking at the game from above:

[image]

You wouldn't lose *too* much of the core gameplay of bowling by not allowing the ball and pins to jump up from the lane. But using a 3d physics engine would certainly help to make the game more realistic, especially when it comes to handling pin-with-pin collision.

But *simulating* the game from above does not necessarily mean that you need to *render* it from above.

Your physics engine should give you just coordinates (x:y or x:y:z, depending on whether you use a 2d or a 3d engine). What you do with those coordinates is up to your rendering loop. A pseudo-3d representation with 2d drawing technology like in the mockup in the question is certainly possible (a common term for this is "2.5d"). You will have to translate the coordinates on the lane to screen coordinates yourself, though, by taking perspective shortening into account (divide width and height of objects by their distance from the viewer). A 3d rendering engine would do that for you, but it is not too difficult to do it on your own. Open a new question if you need help.

Bottom line: You can combine a 2d physics engine with a 3d rendering engine or a 3d physics engine with a 2d rendering engine.